# pochammer symbol and hypergeometric function

Tags: gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

I have the following summation

\begin{equation}
\frac{(39)_3}{3!} + \frac{(34)_8}{8!}+ \frac{(29)_{13}}{13!}+ \frac{(24)_{18}}{18!}
\end{equation}

and i would like to ask if there is any closed form to write it. Observe that the pochhammer symbol is the same as the denominator and each term has a step of 5. So far, I have found that the above can be writen as

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{F_1(-3,38,39,1)} + \frac{1}{F_1(-8,33,34,1)} + \frac{1}{F_1(-13,28,29,1)} + \frac{1}{F_1(-18,23,24,1)} 
\end{equation}
where $F_1$ is the well known hyppergeometric function at $x=1$. I think that i miss an important identity for pochhammer symbols and/or hyppergeometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

$$(a)_b=\frac{\Gamma (a+b)}{\Gamma (a)}$$
$$\frac{(a)_b}{b!}=\frac{\Gamma (a+b)}{\Gamma (a)\, \Gamma (b+1)}$$

So, in you case, the numerator is a constant $\Gamma(?)$. Find it and work the denominators.

Comment: I did it and found 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(42)(\frac{1}{\Gamma(39) \Gamma(4)} + \frac{1}{\Gamma(34) \Gamma(9)} +\frac{1}{\Gamma(29) \Gamma(14)} +\frac{1}{\Gamma(24) \Gamma(19)} )
\end{equation}
Does it simplify?

Comment: @StefanosKomouris.Well, it is an integer with twelve figures.

Comment: hehe, i know that. I was hopping for a generalization like $5^{(?)} \Gamma(?)$